# How to create jsp page content using jquery and use request.getParameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a JSP page which loads another jsp page's content which is working perfectly fine. The problem is I want to pass `request.getParameter("cfgname")` to this content page, so that when it is loaded into the main JSP the content is complete. (Current code shows me `null` in place of `request.getParameter`

Here is my main JSP page which gets `cfgid=41&cfgname=Abhishek&cfgdesc=test1&cfgtype=Development&filepath=files%2Fcsmclientbuckeye.xml`

```
<title>Testing</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   $.get("content.jsp", addContent);

   function addContent(data)
   {
      $("#content").html(data);
   }

 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Content.jsp page

```
<table class="csm-table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th width="25%">Configuration Name</th>
                <td width="25%"><span id="cname"><%= request.getParameter("cfgname") %></span></td>
                <th width="25%">Host Name</th>
                <td width="25%"><span id="chostname">{hostname}</span></td>                
            </tr>
            <tr> </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Configuration Description</th>
                <td><span id="cdesc"><%= request.getParameter("cfgdesc") %></span></td>
                <th width="25%">Os Name</th>
                <td width="25%"><span id="cosname">{osname}</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Configuration Type</th>
                <td><span id="ctype"><%= request.getParameter("cfgtype") %></span></td>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <td><span id="cproductname"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Last Updated Time</th>
                <td><span id="clastupdatetime"></span></td>
                <th>Configuration File Name</th>
                <td><span id="cfilename"><%= request.getParameter("filepath") %></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Both of your (Kees and Mick)'s answer helped me
I did `$.get("content.jsp?cfgname=<%= request.getParameter("cfgname") %>", addContent);` which solved my problem. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks from your code sample like you're calling content.jsp with no parameters:

```
$.get("content.jsp", addContent);
```

You'd need to call it like this:

```
$.get("content.jsp?cfgid=41&cfgname=Abhishek&cfgdesc=test1&cfgtype=Development&filepath=files%2Fcsmclientbuckeye.xml", addContent);
```

Essentially, the AJAX call will not have immediate access to the URL parameters of the page you load first, so if you need to pass them to another HTTP request, which the AJAX call is, then you need to follow the advice of the other poster, to build your query string.

Comment: This `cfgid=41&cfgname=Abhishek&cfgdesc=test1&cfgtype=Development&filepath=files%2Fcsmclientbuckeye.xml` string is dynamic.. so can't use it directly

Comment: Yeah, looks like you need to follow the advice of Kees de Kooter

Comment: Your explanation helped me more so i'll give it to you. Thanks